# Formatting /home directories with terminal

Tags: partitioning, mount, lvm, format

I want to format a hard disk [in terminal] WITHOUT SUDO access and I am not sure how to do this. I will explain what my understanding is and if anyone can help me with how to format and correct my understand I would be most grateful.

Here is the output of `lsblk`:

```
NAME                    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                       8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk  
├─sda1                    8:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2                    8:2    0   488M  0 part  /boot
└─sda3                    8:3    0 464.8G  0 part  
  └─sda3_crypt          252:0    0 464.8G  0 crypt 
    ├─ubuntu--vg-root   252:1    0 460.9G  0 lvm   /
    └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 252:2    0   3.9G  0 lvm   
      └─cryptswap1      252:3    0   3.9G  0 crypt [SWAP]
sr0                      11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

I only want to format the /home directories and as I understand it at this time: the home directories will be within root mountpoint (sda3) because I do not have a specified /home partition in this scenario. So the best I can do would be to format the root mountpoint.

Firstly, would I be able to format the `/` mountpoint without sudo permission?

Secondly, what other information would be within sda3 beside the `/home` directories of the user profiles?

Lastly, does the extended sda3 partitions affect how to format the partition namely of type `lvm` and `crypt`? and would I have to subdivide sda3 if I want the same partition table?

Any help would be appreciated, let me know if you need any further information

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't have `sudo` access? Are you not the administrator on this computer/should not messing stuff up on it, or have you lost access to previously accessible `sudo` permissions?

Comment: Not administrator

Comment: So i need sudo permission if I wish to format the file directories?

Comment: @YinGroen The `/home` root directory is owned by the system.  `/home/$USER` is owned by `$USER`, and the system.  You should not be messing with things if you are not the administrator, as was suggested, as it may cause damage.  I would contact the administrator of the system to ask for changes to be made.